Cannot figure out default value for field: Salescategory salesCategory
cannot generate g dart file with flutter pub run build_runner build which class is shown below and getting this error just because of enum parameter:

enum Salescategory { sales, salesReturn, salesPurchase }

@Entity()
class SalesConverterModel {
  @Id()
  int? id;
  @Property()
  Salescategory salesCategory;
  PartyModel? partyName;
  String? broker;
  String? onAc;
  String? outstate;
  String? qaulity;

  SalesConverterModel({
    this.id,
    this.salesCategory = Salescategory.sales,
    this.partyName,
    this.broker,
    this.onAc,
    this.outstate,
    this.qaulity,
  });
}


Answered on GitHub: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues/647#issuecomment-2199405398
(Also please do not double post, it takes away time from actually answering issues.)

Thank you for the response and for pointing me to the GitHub issue. I apologize for the double post; it wasn't intentional. I'll make sure to avoid it in the future.
